# Installating .NET Core SDK failes silently - how can I install it?

Tags: .net-core, installation, sdk, runtime

I want to install the **.NET Core SDK 1.1** which I downloaded from the site [.NET Core Downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/sdk).

When I try to run the downloaded file `dotnet-1.1.1-sdk-win-x64.exe` nothing happens at all - no windows, no message.

The Windows task manager shows shortly the `dotnet-1.1.1-sdk-win-x64.exe` process which disappears in a second or two.

The same happens when I try with `.NET Core Runtime dotnet-win-x64.1.1.1.exe.`

What does go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can check this page for instructions on how to install via command line and confirm if it's working

https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd

Personally, I prefer installing Visual Studio and letting Visual Studio configure .net core for me as shown in this page

https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2017

Answer (score 0):

First verify 'IIS'and all other windows features(like ASP.NET) are enabled in your machine.
Then try to install dotnet SDK and Visual Studio 2017.
It will work for sure.